# Retrieve datas from session after redirect

Tags: django, forms, redirect

How can i retrieve the data from session within the template after redirecting.Is it possible actually?

Here is my code:

View.py:

```
if request.POST:
user = request.POST.get('username')
passw = request.POST.get('password')
#password1 = ''
try:
    userdata = Employee.objects.get(username = user, password = passw)
    user_id = request.session["user_id"] = userdata.id
    employee_details = Employee.objects.get(id=user_id)
    request.session['emp_details'] = employee_details
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
except Employee.DoesNotExist:
    state = "Username or password incorrect !"
    return render_to_response('login.html',
        {'username' : username1,'state' : state},
        context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

template: home.html

```
<body>
<p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">{{request.session.emp_details.emp_name}}</a></li>
</ul>
</p>
<p><a href="/logout/"><button>logout</button></a></p>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: Am new to django framework,actually am trying to do an application in which the application has an administrator and some users say employees.am using django default login for administrator.But i need a separate login for employees.so i have created a separate class in model for employees for storing username,password and further details.Can i use django default authenticate function for this?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you've added django.core.context_processors.request to your [template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS). Then you can access session variables just as you do in your code.

You may need to add the following line to your view

```
request.session.modified = True
```

This depends on whether you have `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True` in your settings. Have a looks at the [docs for saving sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved).

Lastly, make sure that you're passing a [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) object to the `render_to_response` function in the view at `'/home/'`. The `RequestContext` includes the `request` object in the template context (making it accessable in the template with `{{ request }}`).

WARNING

Whilst this should help you get your sessions working - I have to agree with Daniel, you shouldn't be doing user authentication like this. Use [django's own authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/).